# Dash allow download Excel Linux ubuntu

Tags: python, excel, linux, ubuntu

I'm builing a Dash app on python in which I want to allow users download a selected data to excel. I found a code example to do that and it worked well on windows. However when I cloned that app on my personal computer running ubuntu 18.04 and run the app the downloaded document is not a xlsx  but a compressed file. How could I have a code that work in both?

```py
        # Export to Excel the data filtered
        df_pivot = executive_filtered.pivot(index='period', columns='field', values=fluids)
        str_io = io.BytesIO()
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(str_io,engine = 'openpyxl')
        df_pivot.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"data_{period}")
        writer.save()
        str_io.seek(0)
        media_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        data = base64.b64encode(str_io.read()).decode("utf-8")
        href_data_downloadable = f'data:{media_type};base64,{data}'
```

Comment: _the downloaded document is not a xlsx but a compressed file._ Can you provide more information on the file?

Comment: Based on the first answer I received I manually changed the extension of the downloaded file to .xlsx I was able to open it through LibreOffice. I am using Dash-Bootstrap components, specifically dbc.Buttom in which I set the `href` attribute to ` href_data_downloadable`. So I think now the issue now  is to name properly the file.

Answer (score 0):

An `xlsx` or `xlsm` file **is** basically a zip-file with a bunch of XML (and other) files inside.

On ms-windows, excel files are associated with ms-excel. If you don't have a program that can open excel files installed on Ubuntu, the files in question will probably only be recognized as a zip-file.